# Is there a better way to only run an action once on a loop?

Tags: c++

I have a while loop here and I am running a method called "action" once when a key is pressed.

I need to know if there is a less messy way of doing this.

Here is my current code:

```cpp
bool actionRun = false;
bool keyPress = someCodeForKeyPress;

while(true) {
    if(keyPress) {
        if(!actionRun) {
            action();
            actionRun = true;
        }
    } else {
        actionRun = false;
    }
}
```

In this case, this is redundant but usually why I would want to do this is to have this going on another thread while the main thread is processing key events.

Is there a one-line solution for this?

Comment: Your question is too vague to give a clear answer, but you can bind to the "key released" event instead, as that does not repeat.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

(I'm assuming the snippet you present is run whenever the key is pressed, and you don't really want the loop to run for ever.)

There is a one-liner: `std::call_once`, and it's thread-safe too (your code is vulnerable to data races on the `bool` control variables):

See https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/thread/call_once